# Div to slide under another

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to get an absolutely positioned div element (#slideout) to slide under another div element .menu through CSS if I can.

Here's my: [code](http://the-jeans-shop.com/jquery/toggle/)

As you can see upon clicking the red tab; #slideout covers .menu which is not what I'm after. I would like it to tuck under .menu leaving just the red tab jutting out so a user can then click again to reveal the element.

Things I've tried:
I give .menu a high z-index.
I give #slideout a lower z-index or even no z-index.

This isn't working though.

It would be nice if the whole thing was responsive also. Can you offer me some CSS tricks or even jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Z-index* inherit it's position by the order of the element by default and by positioning *(for example a element with absolute positioning will most likely overlap an element without anypositioning, but as most things it can be difrrent from browser to browser)*, to override it you have to set a positioning {*relative,absolute,fixed*} and then you add the desired z-index.

---

In your case you have to add `position:relative;` to `.menu` for it to work, otherwise as I mentioned earlier it will go after the inheritance of the order of the elements or by which positioning they have.
**CSS:**

```
.menu {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E0E0E0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 99999 !important;
}
```

This will fix everything

Comment: you're welcome, please mark this as answered to the top left of the answer so others can take part of the answer. Cheers =)

Comment: I nearly forgot you're rep!